# How can i add customisation of text to my theme?

Tags: customization

I have a theme with a

```
<h2>Hello</h2>
```

I want a user to be able to come and edit this theme via "Appearence -> Customize".
E.g. by changing the above to

```
<h2> Changed </h2>
```

I have tried looking at
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API
However it doesn't go into any detail about how to change the information.

e.g. it has tautology like

```
"Settings automatically use WordPress's theme_mod features to get/set settings for your theme."
```

Which equates to Settings change Settings????
Is there a tutorial/documentation that tells you how to create a theme customization?

Comment: The updated documentation is at https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/customize-api/ and covers the topic in detail, but even your link describes how to achieve it step by step,

Comment: Thankyou for the response. Click Answer your question and I will mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Also when i look at the documentation to certain wordpress functions. e.g. 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_setting/

It tells me what the parameters are, however never provides a list of parameters. 
Am I missing something ?

Comment: It says "See WP_Customize_Setting::__construct() for information on accepted arguments." right there. Is that what you mean?